# Control knobs of Qsynth using a Novation Launchkey Mini

Tags: sound, music, jack, external-soundcard, audio-recording

I'm using a Novation Launchkey Mini as a Midi controller connected to Qsynth (GUI for FluidSynth) with Qjack, which at the same time is using a Focusrite Scarlett Solo as its audio interface. It all works good, and I'm able to play with the keyboard of the Midi Controller, get sound and record in Audacity.

What I want now is to be able to control the knobs in Qsynth (Room, Damp, Width, etc.) by using the real knobs in the Novation Launchkey.

How can I do this?

My distro is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. I have an Akai MPK mini. I can reprogram the control knobs to any channel control number 1-127 but I dont know what control channel numbers map to the elements in the Qsynth GUI. I've looked at the implementation chart here https://sourceforge.net/p/fluidsynth/wiki/FluidFeatures/ but it's clear as mud. I've also looked at section 8.2.1 of the sf2 spec here http://freepats.zenvoid.org/sf2/sfspec24.pdf. But I still can't figure it out. Also I mapped knob 1 to cc 7 which is volume apparently, but this isn't even a GUI element! totally confused.